# gitolite broken: pull is not possible

Tags: git, gitolite

Some filenames with unicode characters being passed between Windows and *nix have caused some weirdness with gitolite.

This led to files not being able to be ignored/removed from cache, which made merges/rebasing impossible. I added the directory containing the files to my `.gitignore` and removed them from cache. Upon push, `gitolite` is having some issues:

```
remote: U (a bunch of files that were removed from the repo)
remote: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
remote: Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
remote: as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

Everything seems like it is business as usual on the computers that have a copy of the repo, but I'd like to resolve this message. My first intuition was to make some changes on the `gitolite` server directly, but I'm not sure that is the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error looks more like a remote hook trying to pull in changes (being pushed from local) into another repo which seems to a have unmerged changes in the working copy.

Find the hook in the repo you are pushing too ( probably a post-receive), see what it is doing and fix that or fix the other repo that is being operated on in the hook.

Comment: Actually, now that you said that, I think it is trying to update RedMine and that's where it is getting hung up. I'll check it out.

Comment: You're right, as usual! What's the best way to just get these branches synced and ignore local changes? I'd rather not merge a bunch of files. I tried to reset and try the pull again, but it is still whining :)

Comment: @melee Did you do `git reset --hard`?

Comment: Yeah - it's still trying to merge 20 or so files. It is showing that it has diverged - maybe I need to set `HEAD^2`? Edit: Yep, that did it. :)